# Can cv be used to deduple contacts

Tags: cv

civicrm 5.14.1

I have a large number of contacts to dedupe and would like to do it in the background. Is there any way to do this using the cv cli? I am a complete newbie to the API.

Also, what are the environment variables used with cv?